# how to assign value in List<T> type Xml class

Tags: c#, xml

I want to assign value in List. i am not able to understand how can i assign value in List under Stops node. Can you please tell me how can i do this.Below is the code with class file

Created class from XML

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Customer")]
    public class Customer {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="CustomerID")]
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="CustomerCode")]
        public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="OrderStopPiece")]
    public class OrderStopPiece {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Sequence")]
        public string Sequence { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="PieceAction")]
        public string PieceAction { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="OrderStopPieces")]
    public class OrderStopPieces {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="OrderStopPiece")]
        public OrderStopPiece OrderStopPiece { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Stop")]
    public class Stop {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="OrderStopPieces")]
        public OrderStopPieces OrderStopPieces { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Sequence")]
        public string Sequence { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="StopType")]
        public string StopType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Note")]
        public string Note { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Stops")]
    public class Stops {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Stop")]
        public List<Stop> Stop { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Order")]
    public class Order {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Customer")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Stops")]
        public Stops Stops { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="UserID")]
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="CustomerID")]
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="SaveOrder", Namespace="http://www.uBB.com/schemas/")]
    public class SaveOrder {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Order")]
        public Order Order { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="SaveOrder", Namespace="http://www.uBB.com/schemas/")]
        public SaveOrder SaveOrder { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="UserGUID")]
        public string UserGUID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Envelope", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="m", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string M { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="SOAP", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string SOAP { get; set; }
    }
```

Code where i am assiging other values

```
var SaveOrder = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Envelope
                {
                    Body = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Body
                    {
                        UserGUID = guid,
                        SaveOrder = new ECSaveOrderRequest.SaveOrder
                        {
                            Order = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Order
                            {
                                UserID = Uid,
                                Notes = "",
                                CustomerID = "",
                                Customer = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Customer
                                {
                                    CustomerID = "",
                                    CustomerCode = "",
                                    Name = "",
                                    Address = "",
                                    City = ""                                  
                                },
                                Stops = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Stops()
                                { 
                                    Stop = new List<ECSaveOrderRequest.Stop>()
                                    {
                                                /*  Here i want to Assign value in List<stop> */
                                    },

                                },
                                Jobs = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Jobs()
                                {
                                    Job = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Job()
                                    {
                                        Sequence=""
                                    }
                                }                                
                            },
                        }

                     }
                    };
```

Comment: `Stop = new List<ECSaveOrderRequest.Stop>()
                                    {
                                              new ECSaveOrderRequest.Stop(), new ECSaveOrderRequest.Stop()
                                    },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Stops")]
public class Stops {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Stop")]
    public List<Stop> Stop { get; set; }
}
```

You can define a list and populate it outside of the code where you assign values.
When the list has all the values you want it to have, then you can assign the list to the property.

```
Stops = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Stops()
 { 
     Stop = listWithStopValuesYouAssignedOutsideOfThisCodeBlock
 }
```

Or another way of doing is by adding a new stop to the list like

```
Stop = new List<ECSaveOrderRequest.Stop>()
    {
     new ECSaveOrderRequest.Stop() {},
     new ECSaveOrderRequest.Stop() {},
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
Stops = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Stops()
                                { 
                                    Stop = new List<ECSaveOrderRequest.Stop>
                                    {
                                        new ECSaveOrderRequest.Stop                                         {
                                            Sequence = "",
                                            StopType = ""
                                            // rest of properties
                                        },
                                        new ECSaveOrderRequest.Stop                                         {
                                            Sequence = "",
                                            StopType = ""
                                            // rest of properties
                                        },
                                    }

                                },
```

But a better (more readable) solution would be create the List of Stop first and then assign it to Stops.Stop.

```
Stops = new ECSaveOrderRequest.Stops()
                                { 
                                 Stop = listOfStops
                                }
```